# Primary node of MongoDB ReplicaSet constantly high cpu usage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

We use mongo replicaSet version 3.4.2 on our production environments. The replicaSet works with 6 nodes , one primary and 5 secondaries. Few weeks ago we have started to get alerts on high cpu consumption on the primary node.

At the beginning we thought that we should separate the load between the members so we configured our service to make reads from secondaries and write to the primary. Unfortunately we are still on the same point.

The cpu of the primary node is between 70-100% even on idle times while the secondaries consumes maximum of 20%. It is important to mention that we creates DB for each one of our customers with average of 9 indexes each - we have 1500DB's like that.

diagnostic data - metrics: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11ejEjDA-XiSHFUWll3cmlHeUE/view?usp=sharing

mongostat log: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11ejEjDA-XiNEJwTXkzSkZMNWM/view?usp=sharing

let me know if more information requierd.

Thanks,

Roie.

Comment: What program should we use to open that diagnostic data binary file?  Can you give result (60 sec) of command `mongostat -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin --discover`

Comment: sure, here is a link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11ejEjDA-XibUF4aTNtMEw4eEE/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, cannot find any reason for high CPU load. Not much happening on primary, everything looks fine. What is result (when CPU load is high) of `top -n 1` command?

Comment: PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND


 1493 999       20   0 5362524 3.625g   5436 S 111.7 46.5 790:25.38 mongod
    1 root      20   0   33640   2848   1312 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.61 init

Comment: What I wanted to see was top commands first four lines at least. Section what summarize everything, if you cannot provide the whole result. "Tasks:, Cpu(s):, Mem:, Swap:"

Comment: sorry for the delay , here is a link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B11ejEjDA-XiMVZmR2lDU1FWSXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Because your mongostat showed "getmore" spikes, I guess that, that 8GB memory of mongod node is not enough to hold all active data in the memory. Can you (easily) test what will happen if you give 16 (or more) memory to the mongo node? How many CPUs this node have? More than one is good and four should be enough.

Comment: based on your assumption , why the secondaries have no cpu usage at all? they don't suppose to replicate the same operations?

Comment: Yes, secondaries replicate changes. But getmore comes when application makes query where node (primary) cannot give whole result at once. When cursor is bigger than batch size. Secondaries don't "answer" queries, normally all query traffic goes to primary.

Comment: Hi, i configured my services to read from salves. is that still query the primary somehow? regarding to the memory size , i raised the machine from 4GB to 8 GB due to the same behaviour.

Comment: If query goes to secondaries (only) and writes goes to primaries, only read to primary is then replication.

Comment: any idea how i can catch problematic queries such as the getmore you mentioned?

Comment: Check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/